# Where is the echo command for a HTTP request?

Tags: php, http, pear

I might be asking the wrong question here, but I cant seem to figure out where this is coming form. I am using both the HTTP Request2 and NET URL2 libraries in order to send some GET request to the Vuforia web services. This all works fine, but everytime I send a request, it also shows said request on screen.

```
GET d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e Mon, 09 Dec 2019 22:49:52 GMT /summary/ba2246f8cd29466899c69b8d05af09a1
```

The code that I use to get the above text appear on screen is as follows.
Main code:

```
<?php if(sizeof($items) > 0){
    foreach($items as $item){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo'<td>'.$item['itemid'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$item['name'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$item['surname'].'</td>';
        echo'<td>'.$item['phone'].'</td>';
        $recos = $targetdata = json_decode(CheckVuforiaTarget("ba2246f8cd29466899c69b8d05af09a1"), true);
        echo'<td>'.$recos['current_month_recos'].'</td>';
        }
    } else echo '<tr><td>Geen kandidaten</td></tr>';?>
```

Script holding the CheckVuforiaTarget function:

```
function CheckVuforiaTarget($vuforiaid){
        $vuforiaTargetTracker = new TargetTracker($vuforiaid);
        $response = $vuforiaTargetTracker->TargetTracker();
        return ($response);
        //print_r($vuforiaResult);
    }
```

TargetTracker class:

```
<?php

require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';
require_once 'SignatureBuilder.php';

// See the Vuforia Web Services Developer API Specification - https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/retrieving-target-cloud-database
// The DeleteTarget sample demonstrates how to delete a target from its Cloud Database using the target's target id.
// * note that targets cannot be 'Processing' and must be inactive to be deleted.

class TargetTracker{

    //Server Keys
    private $access_key     = "...";
    private $secret_key     = "...";

    private $url            = "https://vws.vuforia.com";
    private $requestPath    = "/summary/";
    private $request;

    private $targetId       = "";

    public function __construct($targetId) {
        $this->targetId = $targetId;
    }

    function TargetTracker(){
        $this->requestPath = $this->requestPath . $this->targetId;      
        return $this->execTargetTracker();
    }

    public function execTargetTracker(){

        $this->request = new HTTP_Request2();
        $this->request->setMethod( HTTP_Request2::METHOD_GET );     
        $this->request->setConfig(array('ssl_verify_peer' => false));

        $this->request->setURL( $this->url . $this->requestPath );
        $this->setHeaders();

        try {

            $response = $this->request->send();

            if (200 == $response->getStatus()) {
                return $response->getBody();
            } else {
                //echo 'Unexpected HTTP status: ' . $response->getStatus() . ' ' .
                //      $response->getReasonPhrase(). ' ' . $response->getBody();
                return $response->getBody();
            }
        } catch (HTTP_Request2_Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    private function setHeaders(){
        $sb =   new SignatureBuilder();
        $date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("GMT"));

        // Define the Date field using the proper GMT format
        $this->request->setHeader('Date', $date->format("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT" );
        // Generate the Auth field value by concatenating the public server access key w/ the private query signature for this request
        $this->request->setHeader("Authorization" , "VWS " . $this->access_key . ":" . $sb->tmsSignature( $this->request , $this->secret_key ));

    }
}

?>
```

Both HTTP/Request2.php(and everything it came with) and SignatureBuilder.php are both default scripts/classes I've downloaded from the internet without altering them.

Now with my basic understanding of PHP, i've tried to find anything related to an echo or whatever command would show this on screen, but I can't seem to find it.

Does someone have some pointers for me, so I can figure out the source?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided has no echo/print output that would explain the message you see. The echo/print statement must be somewhere else.